# How do I make this output a boolean?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, return

So here's my code, I want the output to be like this:

Given two numbers, is the second input a multiple of the first?

For Example:

Input:

> 3
>
> 6

Output:

> true

```
public boolean multiple(int m, int n){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    boolean check = true;
    if(n%m == 0){
        i++;
        return check;
    }
    else{
        j++;
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try it I get an error, I think it's because the return statement is within the if and else statements.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Looks like your error is elsewhere in your code...

Comment: @ramansb do you have a closing } on your method?

Comment: I mean I'm not getting any output, nothing returns I see nothing.

Comment: @RamanSB show the rest of your code because that is where your problem is...

Comment: You do not need variables i and j  nor do you need the check variable. Just return true in lieu of check.

Comment: You need an actual line that outputs things in your main method.  Something like System.out.println(multiple(5, 10));

Answer (score 1):

The code is perfectly fine .. Error must be Somewhere else

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(multiple(3, 9));

}
    public static boolean multiple(int m, int n){

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        boolean check = true;
        if(n%m == 0){
            i++;
            return check;
        }
        else{
            j++;
            return false;
        }
        }
}
```

Output
`true`

here is output see [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/mPug5t)

Comment: Welcome :) Btw its not Object its method .. Object is completely different thing buddy !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to return the result of your `if` statement.

```
return n % m == 0;
```

I'm not sure what i/j are doing. You don't use them except to increment, but they are local to the function and get GC'd after the return. What you have now is basically this:

```
boolean bool = some_calculation();
if (bool == true)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```